Using a greyscale image as a weight map for point distribution
I imported this image with blender GIS using the basemap on mesh option. I'm trying to use this image as a weight map that distributes points randomly on my mesh, where darker colours indicates a lower density of points and lighter colours indicate a higher density of points.


Here is my geometry node set up and material panel:

I am trying to instance cubes along the mesh but it doesn't seem to be working. No points are being generated from the distribute points on faces node. What is going wrong here?

how many faces does it mesh have? in geometry node the geometry (here face) are like pixels, i.e. the distribute points on faces node reads the density (and the other inputs') data from the face domain, so if you have only one face then you will only read the texture at one point (in the middle).

The mesh I'm using has 2.3 M faces, so I don't think it's a face issue.

i just looked st the picture you sent and I see the problem. you didn't select sn image in the node, so it's not reading anything.
